# Do I need to boil the water before using my moka?

Tags: moka

I was recently told that I could improve the flavour of my moka pot coffee by boiling the water separately before putting it in the pot and assembling it.

The theory goes that this means that the pot spends less time on the stove, meaning the grounds are less likely to be burned from the heat of the pot before the water has a chance to turn into steam and brew the coffee.

Is this true?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is true.

Preboiling the water will make the coffee tastes a lot better. It will reduce the bitterness and give space for a lot of other notes.

Heating up the Mokka too much releases also metallic taste from the machine itself and you boil the coffee.