# How should I make multiple batches quickly with a moka pot?

Tags: moka

I made three batches in a row with a moka pot (for Vietnamese coffee ice cream!) recently. I did my best to handle things with a wet rag while still hot, but it was still a bit of a pain and a bit slow. Is there anything else I can do to speed things along or make it easier? Is it safe to just run water over it to fully cool it down?

Comment: Fraught with peril! One way to speed up is to [pre-boil the water as suggested in this answer](http://coffee.stackexchange.com/a/130/262), but otherwise I haven't figured a good way except use a bigger moka pot; hopefully someone else has better ideas.

Comment: Handle with a wet rag while still hot? If you're talking about handlig hot materials and not getting burnt, use a dry rag instead! Water conducts heat very well.

Comment: @Ludwik The point is that water has a high heat capacity, so a rag wet with cool or room temperature water is enough to cool things down enough to handle. A dry rag will insulate you for a bit... and then just get hot, and keep being hot. (Side note: water is actually a bad heat conductor, worse than glass, for example. It's normally pretty good at heat transfer because of convection, not conduction. And if it's already hot, it transfers a lot of heat via conduction because of the heat capacity, not the conductivity.)

Comment: @Jefromi Well, you clearly have it sorted out, just wanted to be on the safe side ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's what I do:

- Boil a kettle with as much water as you're going to need for everyone
- Fill the sink with cold water
- Make your pot of coffee as normal: using boiling water
- After you've made the coffee and poured it out, dunk the pot in the sink of cold water
- It should cool down within a few seconds, allowing you to unscrew it, clean it out, and reset (it helps if you have a second sink to do the cleaning in)
- Fill with coffee/boiling water again, and repeat until everyone has coffee

Comment: So no problems from shocking it with all that cold water? Awesome!

Comment: @Jefromi AFAIK Aluminium should have no problem being quenched like that.

Comment: I do this too, and so far no problems with the aluminium pot. But it's still easier to just use a bigger pot, or it's a nice excuse to get another one :)